# Singularity sandbox file management

Tags: singularity-container

Fed up with struggling with lib install/dependencies problems, I'm starting working with Singularity.
Though, I'm not sure I understand precisely how it works regarding files management in the sandbox mode (not data, programs).
For example, I designed a very simple definition file that is just a "naked" Debian:

```
Bootstrap: library
From: debian

%post
apt-get update
```

I create a sandbox with this to add stuff:

```
sudo singularity build --sandbox Test/ naked_Debian.def
```

And I try to install a program. But what I don't understand is that I managed to do it, removed the sandbox directory but I think there are still files that were created during the sandbox life (in /dev, /run, /root, etc.). For example, the program that I cloned from git is now in /root of my local (independently of any container).
From what I understood, everything was in the container and should disappear if I remove the sandbox directory. Otherwise, I'm gonna leave a lot of mess with all the tests? And then I can't port the container from system to another.

If I create any new sandbox directory, the program is already there.

Cheers,
Mathieu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, singularity mounts `$HOME` to the container and uses that path as the working directory for `singularity shell / exec`. Since you're running the sandbox with sudo, `/root` is being mounted in and that's where any repos you cloned would end up if you didn't `cd` to a different directory. `/tmp` is also automatically mounted in, though that is unlikely to cause an issue since it's just temp files.

You have a few options to avoid files ending up in places you don't expect.

1. Disable automount of home: `singularity shell --no-home ...`

   - The default working directory is now `/` instead of `$HOME` and files are created directly in sandbox (as opposed to a mounted in directory)
   - If you want to get files out of the sandbox, you'll either need to copy to `/tmp` inside the container, and on the host OS from `/tmp` to the desired location
2. Set a different location to use as home: `singularity shell --home $PWD ...`

   - This mounts in and uses the current directory as `$HOME` instead of the user's `$HOME` on the host OS
   - Simpler to move files between host OS and container, but still creates files in the host OS
3. Don't mount system directories at all: `singularity shell --contain --workdir /some/dir ...`

   - Directories for `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` are created inside `/some/dir` instead of using `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` on the host. `$HOME` has the same path as the host and is used as the working directory, but it is empty and separate from the host OS
   - Complete separation from host OS, while still allowing some access between container and OS

Additional details on these options [can be found in the documentation](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/cli/singularity_shell.html#options).

Comment: Thanks tsnowlan for this detailed answer!
So, if I understand correctly, the way the file are managed is independent of the "build sandox" command but totally rely on how you will "enter" the sandbox container with "shell"?